# Show an icon on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angular and I want to show an icon after ng-click triggered a function call.
how can I do it? I have tried ng-if for this but its not working.
please provide me the solution.

```html
<li ng-click="bookmark(question)"><a><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmark</a></li>
```

```html
<i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
```

this is my ng-click and I want icon of bookmark on click of function.
How can I do it?

Comment: where do you want the icon.. pleases be a bit more elaborative

Comment: @San use ng-show directive to display icon. when click on link set variable to true to display icon

Comment: the simplest solution would be to add a bookmarked attribute in your `question object` like in your `bookmarked(question)` function do something like `question.bookmarked = !question.bookmarked` and modify your icon html to `<i ng-show = "question.bookmarked" class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>`

Comment: I want icon on the top right corner

Comment: @Mubashir I tried this but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-show` or `ng-if` (ng-if removes the elements from dom and adds it according to your logic).

**Template**

```
<li ng-click="bookmark(question)"><a ng-show="showIcon"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>Bookmark</a></li>
```

**controller**

```
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

   $scope.showIcon = false; // initially false

   $scope.bookmark = function(){
     $scope.showIcon = true;
   }

}])
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest solution would be to add a `bookmarked` attribute in your `question object` like in your `bookmarked(question) function` do something like `question.bookmarked = !question.bookmarked` and modify your icon html to

```
<i ng-show = "question.bookmarked" class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have one flag inside `question` object, that will represent state of to show bookmark or not. OR you could use `ng-if`/`ng-show` to show hide DOM.

**Makrup**

```
<li ng-click="bookmark(question)">
  <a>
     <!--<i class="fa" ng-class="{'fa-bookmark': question.isBookmarked }"></i>-->
     <i ng-if="question.isBookmarked" class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>
  Bookmark</a>
</li>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.bookmark = function(question){
   //do other code here.
   question.isBookmarked = true;
}
```

Comment: @San does it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

use ng-show directive to display icon. i put sample code here.

```js
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  
  $scope.bookmark = false;
  
  $scope.isBookmark = function(bookmark){
    if(bookmark)
       $scope.bookmark = false;
    else
      $scope.bookmark = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
        <li>
            <i class="icon icon-bookmark" ng-show="bookmark">Bookmark</i><a ng-click="isBookmark(bookmark)"> click </a>
        </li>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```